# Some videos fail to chromecast with error MEDIA_UNKNOWN

Tags: ffmpeg, chromecast

Using `mkchromecast` to cast local mp4 files, some videos work, and some don't (as in: the screen hangs on the blue chromecast logo, suggesting that the initial connection worked). I can reproduce exactly the issue described [here](https://github.com/muammar/mkchromecast/issues/254).

So I decided to go one level lower, with `pychromecast`, and try to see what actually happens when it hangs on the blue logo. I converted two videos to HLS format, and exposed them through an http server. The video that works with `mkchromecast` also works with my setup, but the one that fails, well... fails on both. With `pychromecast`, I don't get much more information than:

> ERROR, code 100: MEDIA_UNKNOWN.

From the [Cast documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/error_codes#media_player_library_error_codes), this error means:

> The media element encountered an unknown error fired from platform. The media element encountered an error that did not indicate it's one of MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_*. This should be rare.

It is not rare for me at all, though. I thought that maybe the failing video was in an unsupported format, as described [in the documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#mp4_video_and_audio). So I tried to compare both videos with the following command:

```
ffprobe -v quiet -print_format json -show_streams <video.mp4>
```

#### Video that works:

```
{
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "1001/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1080,
            "coded_width": 1920,
            "coded_height": 1088,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "16:9",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 50,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "avg_frame_rate": "24000/1001",
            "time_base": "1/24000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 47127080,
            "duration": "1963.628333",
            "bit_rate": "5527977",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "47080",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "VideoHandler"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
            "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 2,
            "channel_layout": "stereo",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 94254528,
            "duration": "1963.636000",
            "bit_rate": "125776",
            "max_bit_rate": "125776",
            "nb_frames": "92048",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "SoundHandler"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

#### Video that does NOT work:

```
{                                               
    "streams": [
        {
            "index": 0,
            "codec_name": "h264",
            "codec_long_name": "H.264 / AVC / MPEG-4 AVC / MPEG-4 part 10",
            "profile": "High",
            "codec_type": "video",
            "codec_time_base": "125/5994",
            "codec_tag_string": "avc1",
            "codec_tag": "0x31637661",
            "width": 1920,
            "height": 1040,
            "coded_width": 1920,
            "coded_height": 1040,
            "has_b_frames": 2,
            "sample_aspect_ratio": "1:1",
            "display_aspect_ratio": "24:13",
            "pix_fmt": "yuv420p",
            "level": 41,
            "chroma_location": "left",
            "refs": 1,
            "is_avc": "true",
            "nal_length_size": "4",
            "r_frame_rate": "2997/125",
            "avg_frame_rate": "2997/125",
            "time_base": "1/11988",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 97032000,
            "duration": "8094.094094",
            "bit_rate": "2499644",
            "bits_per_raw_sample": "8",
            "nb_frames": "194064",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "2020-03-27T09:56:39.000000Z",
                "language": "und",
                "handler_name": "L-SMASH Video Media Handler"
            }
        },
        {
            "index": 1,
            "codec_name": "aac",
            "codec_long_name": "AAC (Advanced Audio Coding)",
            "profile": "LC",
            "codec_type": "audio",
            "codec_time_base": "1/48000",
            "codec_tag_string": "mp4a",
            "codec_tag": "0x6134706d",
            "sample_fmt": "fltp",
            "sample_rate": "48000",
            "channels": 6,
            "channel_layout": "5.1",
            "bits_per_sample": 0,
            "r_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "avg_frame_rate": "0/0",
            "time_base": "1/48000",
            "start_pts": 0,
            "start_time": "0.000000",
            "duration_ts": 388516320,
            "duration": "8094.090000",
            "bit_rate": "224000",
            "max_bit_rate": "224000",
            "nb_frames": "379413",
            "disposition": {
                "default": 1,
                "dub": 0,
                "original": 0,
                "comment": 0,
                "lyrics": 0,
                "karaoke": 0,
                "forced": 0,
                "hearing_impaired": 0,
                "visual_impaired": 0,
                "clean_effects": 0,
                "attached_pic": 0,
                "timed_thumbnails": 0
            },
            "tags": {
                "creation_time": "2020-03-27T09:56:39.000000Z",
                "language": "eng",
                "handler_name": "SoundHandler"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

For what I can see, the codecs are the same, and the only difference I can make is in the aspect ratio.

What could be the reason for this "MEDIA_UNKNOWN" error on the chromecast side? Is there something more I could compare between those two videos? Could it be that the chromecast fails because of the aspect ratio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It does not like 5.1 channel layout. Try downmixing it to stereo:

```
ffmpeg -i not_working.mp4 -c copy -c:a aac -ac 2 -movflags +faststart fixed.mp4
```

Comment: Amazing, that works (at least for this video)! Thank you so much! Is there a hint somewhere in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/media#mp4_video_and_audio) saying that 5.1 is not supported? I'm not sure what to look for there...

Comment: @JonasVautherin It was just a lazy guess. I didn't look up any Cast docs.

Comment: Right. Good guess then ;-)